# draw a coverage area of map in google map in android like web

Tags: android, google-maps

hello I want to draw a coverage area of map on google map in android e.g A telecom company has coverage in all newyork so I want to fill all newyork with different color with any color.

I am looking for reply

Thanks

Comment: i suppose you are looking for https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CircleOptions

Comment: it doesnt help me anybody have a solution.

Comment: you want to draw something on the map that signifies coverage right ?

Comment: yes like a mobile serv ice provider company have coverage on following area.e.g japan , US etc so highlight all those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you can achieve this with  circleoption on google map:

```
        CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions();
        co.center(point);
        co.radius(distance);
        co.strokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
        co.strokeWidth(2.0f);
        co.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#8CFFFFFF"));
        googleMap.addCircle(co);
```

Comment: Sets the center using a LatLng.

The center must not be null.

This method is mandatory because there is no default center.

Comment: accepting the answer  if it help would be appreciated.